# not able to select in Group by Entity Framework

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I have this SQL query which I am trying to translate into Linq

```
SELECT 
    DATEPART(yyyy, ce.DueDate) AS year,
    DATEPART(mm, ce.DueDate) AS Month,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN rt.Code = 'Pass' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS NumPass,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN rt.Code = 'Fail' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS NumFail
FROM
    ControlEvent ce
INNER JOIN 
    ProcessEvent pe ON pe.ControlEventId = ce.Id
INNER JOIN 
    ResultType rt ON pe.ResultTypeId = rt.Id
WHERE 
    DATEDIFF(dd,ce.DueDate,GETDATE()) <= 0
    AND DATEDIFF(dd,ce.DueDate,DATEADD(mm, 3, GETDATE())) >= 0
    AND pe.ProcessId = 1040
GROUP BY 
    DATEPART(yyyy, ce.DueDate), DATEPART(mm, ce.DueDate)
ORDER BY 
    DATEPART(yyyy, ce.DueDate), DATEPART(mm, ce.DueDate)
```

I have done this till now

```
var result =
   (from ce in ControlEvents

    join pe in ProcessEvents on ce.Id equals pe.ControlEventId
    join rt in ResultTypes on pe.ResultTypeId equals rt.Id into resultType

    where ce.DueDate >= startDate &&
    ce.DueDate <= endDate &&
    pe.ProcessId == 1048

    orderby ce.DueDate.Value.Year, ce.DueDate.Value.Month

    group ce by new {
       ce.DueDate.Value.Year,
       ce.DueDate.Value.Month,
    } into g

    select new {
       g.Key.Year,
       g.Key.Month,
    }

    ).ToList();
```

My question is how can I bring the case statements from my SQL query to linq Select. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, remove `into resultType` because it creates a group join, and your SQL query does not use such construct.

Second, move the `orderby` clause after `groupby`.

Finally, use the fact that SQL `Count(CASE WHEN condition THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)` is equivalent to `SUM(condition, 1, 0)` which is supported by LINQ.

So the equivalent LINQ query could be something like this:

```
var result =
   (from ce in ControlEvents
    join pe in ProcessEvents on ce.Id equals pe.ControlEventId
    join rt in ResultTypes on pe.ResultTypeId equals rt.Id
    where ce.DueDate >= startDate &&
        ce.DueDate <= endDate &&
        pe.ProcessId == 1048
    group rt by new {
       ce.DueDate.Value.Year,
       ce.DueDate.Value.Month,
    } into g
    orderby g.Key.Year, g.Key.Month
    select new {
       g.Key.Year,
       g.Key.Month,
       NumPass = g.Sum(e => e.Code == "Pass" ? 1 : 0),
       NumFail = g.Sum(e => e.Code == "Fail" ? 1 : 0)
    }
   ).ToList();
```

And the resulting EF6.1.3 generated SQL query looks like this:

```
SELECT 
    [Project1].[C5] AS [C1], 
    [Project1].[C3] AS [C2], 
    [Project1].[C4] AS [C3], 
    [Project1].[C1] AS [C4], 
    [Project1].[C2] AS [C5]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1], 
        [GroupBy1].[A2] AS [C2], 
        [GroupBy1].[K1] AS [C3], 
        [GroupBy1].[K2] AS [C4], 
        1 AS [C5]
        FROM ( SELECT 
            [Filter1].[K1] AS [K1], 
            [Filter1].[K2] AS [K2], 
            SUM([Filter1].[A1]) AS [A1], 
            SUM([Filter1].[A2]) AS [A2]
            FROM ( SELECT 
                DATEPART (year, [Extent1].[DueDate]) AS [K1], 
                DATEPART (month, [Extent1].[DueDate]) AS [K2], 
                CASE WHEN (N'Pass' = [Extent3].[Code]) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [A1], 
                CASE WHEN (N'Fail' = [Extent3].[Code]) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [A2]
                FROM   [dbo].[ControlEvents] AS [Extent1]
                INNER JOIN [dbo].[ProcessEvents] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[Id] = [Extent2].[ControlEventId]
                INNER JOIN [dbo].[ResultTypes] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent2].[ResultTypeId] = [Extent3].[Id]
                WHERE ([Extent1].[DueDate] >= @p__linq__0) AND ([Extent1].[DueDate] <= @p__linq__1) AND ([Extent2].[ProcessId] = @p__linq__2)
            )  AS [Filter1]
            GROUP BY [K1], [K2]
        )  AS [GroupBy1]
    )  AS [Project1]
    ORDER BY [Project1].[C3] ASC, [Project1].[C4] ASC
```

Comment: what if I want to group by Year and then by Week? How I can do that in Linq?

Comment: There is no standard canonical function. If you target SqlServer only, you can use [SqlFunctions.DatePart](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487171(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: did some more testing and turns out to be the sum statements are bringing sum of ControlEvent.ResultTypes.Pass or Fail whereas I was interested in ProcessEvent.ResultType.Pass or Fail. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Tables, joins and columns are the same as in your SQL query, so should be the results. Are you saying you are looking for a different query than the SQL one?

Comment: no my sql query is returning correct results but the Linq is returning Count  of ControlEvent.ResultType.Code pass or fail where it should return Count(ProcessType.ResultType.Code pass or fail)
Linq is not respecting this join (    join rt in ResultTypes on pe.ResultTypeId equals rt.Id
) i guess

Comment: Hmm, see the SQL query I'm getting from EF - looks like the original to me.

Comment: I think you are right my mistake was i was doing
    group ce by new { whereas you suggested
    group rt by new {
changing groupby from ce to rt seems to produce correct result. Is that your understanding as well

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there. Just before your select statement you had a sequence of groups, where each group was a sequence of join results, where each join result had the same year / month.

So for example you had the following groups

- group1 (January 2015) = sequence of join results with duedate jan 2015
- group2 (February 2015) = sequence of join results with duedate feb 2015
- group3 (February 2015) = sequence of join results with duedate mar 2015

You already found out that the key contained the year and the month you wanted.

For NumPass of group jan 2015, you want all elements of the sequence of jan 2015 that match joinResult.resultType.code == "Pass",

As an object oriented programmer I always have a bit of difficulty writing my Linq statements in this half SQL like syntax, so if it does not bother you too much, I rewrote it using lambda expressions:

```
ControlEvents.Join(ProcessEvents,
    key1 => key1.Id,              // from ControlEvents take Id
    key2 => key2.ControlEventId   // from processEventt take ControlEventId
    (x, y) => new                 // where they match,
    {
        DueDate = x.DueDate,           // take ControlEvent.Duedate
        ProcessId = y.ProcessId,       // take ProcessId.Id
        ResultTypeId = y.ResultTypeId, // take Process.ResultTypeId
    })

.Where (joinResult =>                  // limit the join result before the 2nd join
    joinResult.DueDate >= startDate &&
    joinResult.DueDate <= endDate &&
    joinResult.ProcessId == 1048)

.Join(ResultTypes,             // join the previous result with ResultTypes
    key1 => key1.ResultTypeId  // from previous join take ResultTypeId
    key2 => key2.Id            // from ResultTypes takd Id
    (x, y) => new              // where they match, take:
    {
        Year = x.DueDate.year,
        Month = x.DueDate.Month,
        // ProcessId = x.ProcessId, not needed anymore
        // unless you want the where statement after the 2nd join 
        ResultCode = y.Code,
    })
 .Orderby(joinResult => joinResult.Year)
 .ThenBy(joinResult => joinResult.Month)
 .GroupBy(sortResult => new {Year = sortResult.Year, Month = sortResult.Month}
```

- by now you have groups with key {Year, Month}.
- Each group has a sequence of objects with properties { Year, Month, ResultCode}
- Within one group the Year / Month are all the same

Now all you have to do is count all elements within one group that match "Pass" and those that match "Fail":

Continuing the LINQ statement:

```
.Select(group => new
{
    Year = group.key.Year,
    Month = group.key.Month,
    NumPass = group
        .Where(groupElement => groupElement.ResultCode.Equals("Pass"))
        .Count(),
    NumFail = group
        .Where(groupElement => groupElement.ResultCode.Equals("Fail"))
        .Count(),
 }
 .ToList();
```

This should do the trick.

Note that I put your Where statement for ProcessId == 1048 before the 2nd join, because I guess that limits the amount of items to join. Maybe the following would even be smarter:

```
ControlEvents
    .Where(controlEvent => controlEvent.DueDate >= startDate
           && controlEvent.DueDate <= endDate)
    .Join (ProcessEvents.Where(processEvent => processEvent.Id == 1048),
           key1 => etc,
```

I guess this would really limit the number of elements to join.

Also, consider ordering by Year / Month after the final select, because in that case you also have to order over a much smaller collection

Comment: count statements are bringing sum of ControlEvent.ResultTypes.Pass or Fail whereas I was expecting ProcessEvent.ResultType.Pass or Fail. Any views on that?

Comment: you wrote "count statements are bringing sum of...". Are you sure? I really do think that Count() returns the number of elements that match the where statement. Consider using Enumerable.Count(this source, Func<TSource, Boolean>) instead of the where. You also wrote: "I was expecting ProcessEvent.ResultType.Pass..." your SQL statement does not return the value ProcessEvent.ResultType, if counts the number of ProcessEvents.ResultType that have a value "Pass"